# CSS-HTML Cut hyperlink tag in half

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create two "buttons" with A tag, so they both will be cut in half, and so they both will be kinda like, finishing each other. (illustration below)

I wasn't able to achieve it. Any ideas? I was trying to place A tag inside DIV and set width and overflow of that DIV to hidden, but it didn't work as I expected. I currently have no code to show you, so I will be starting from nothing.

[image]

Comment: google the :before and :after with css.

Comment: wow, that's the thing. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use pseudo-elements - `:before` and `:after`

gradient - http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

```css
a{
    padding: 20px 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #880015;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-left: 5px solid #880015;
    border-right: 5px solid #FF7F27;
    position: relative;
}
a span{
    color: #FF7F27;
}
a:before,
a:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;  left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background: #880015; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #880015 0%, #880015 50%, #ff7f27 50%, #ff7f27 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#880015), color-stop(50%,#880015), color-stop(50%,#ff7f27), color-stop(100%,#ff7f27)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #880015 0%,#880015 50%,#ff7f27 50%,#ff7f27 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #880015 0%,#880015 50%,#ff7f27 50%,#ff7f27 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #880015 0%,#880015 50%,#ff7f27 50%,#ff7f27 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #880015 0%,#880015 50%,#ff7f27 50%,#ff7f27 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#880015', endColorstr='#ff7f27',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
a:before{
    top: 0;
}
a:after{
    bottom: 0;
}


a:hover{
    border-right: 5px solid #880015;
    border-left: 5px solid #FF7F27;
}
a:hover:before,
a:hover:after{
    background: #ff7f27; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #ff7f27 0%, #ff7f27 50%, #880015 50%, #880015 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#ff7f27), color-stop(50%,#ff7f27), color-stop(50%,#880015), color-stop(100%,#880015)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #ff7f27 0%,#ff7f27 50%,#880015 50%,#880015 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #ff7f27 0%,#ff7f27 50%,#880015 50%,#880015 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #ff7f27 0%,#ff7f27 50%,#880015 50%,#880015 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #ff7f27 0%,#ff7f27 50%,#880015 50%,#880015 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff7f27', endColorstr='#880015',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
```

```html
<a href="#">Li<span>nk</span></a>
```